# Need some logical guide line for generating a concatenation data SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Based on start & end year input and start & end month input I want to generate output like

```
2010-MAR 2010-APR 2010-MAY 2010-JUN 2010-JULY 2010-AUG 2010-SEP so on
```

Here is my script which works fine but if start month number is bigger than end month number then a logical problem occur.

```
DECLARE @StartYear AS INT,
        @EndYear  AS INT

DECLARE @LowerBound AS INT,
        @UpperBound  AS INT

DECLARE @StartMonth AS VARCHAR(10),
        @EndMonth  AS VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @ConCatData VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ConCatData=''

SET @StartYear=2009
SET @EndYear=2010

SET @StartMonth='March'
SET @EndMonth='February'

WHILE(@StartYear <= @EndYear)
BEGIN

    SET @LowerBound = CAST(MONTH('1'+@StartMonth+'00') as INT)
    SET @UpperBound = CAST(MONTH('1'+@EndMonth+'00') as INT)

    WHILE( @LowerBound <= @UpperBound )
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ConCatData=CAST(@StartYear AS VARCHAR)+'-'+ DateName( month , DateAdd( month ,@LowerBound , -1 ) )
        SET @LowerBound=@LowerBound+1
        PRINT @ConCatData
    END
    SET @StartYear=@StartYear+1
END
```

I want that if user inputs

- start year : 2009 end year : 2009
- start month : MAR end MON : SEP

then output will be

```
2009-MAR 2009-APR 2009-MAY 2009-JUN 2009-JUL 2009-AUG so on....
```

If user inputs

- start year : 2009 end year : 2010
- start month : MAR end MON : FEB

then output will be

```
2009-MAR 2009-APR 2009-MAY 2009-JUN 2009-JUL 2009-AUG so on.... 2010-JAN 2010-FEB
```

I need some logical help. If possible please rectify my code or tell me where to rectify to draw my expected output. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this help.

```
DECLARE @StartYear AS INT,
        @EndYear  AS INT

DECLARE @LowerBound AS DATETIME,
        @UpperBound  AS DATETIME

DECLARE @StartMonth AS VARCHAR(10),
        @EndMonth  AS VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @ConCatData VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ConCatData=''

SET @StartYear=2009
SET @EndYear=2009

SET @StartMonth='March'
SET @EndMonth='September'


    SET @LowerBound = '1 '+@StartMonth+' ' + CAST(@StartYear AS char(4))
    SET @UpperBound = '1 '+@EndMonth+' ' + CAST(@EndYear AS char(4))

    WHILE( @LowerBound <= @UpperBound )
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ConCatData=CAST(Year(@LowerBound) AS CHAR(4))+'-'+ Upper(Convert(char(3), @LowerBound, 100 ))
        PRINT @ConCatData
        SET @LowerBound=DateAdd(month, 1, @LowerBound)
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

How about a set-based solution:

```
declare @startYear as int = 2009
declare @startMonth as int = 3
declare @endYear as int = 2010
declare @endMonth as int = 2
;with [dates] as (
    select convert(date, cast(@startYear as varchar(5)) + 
        RIGHT('0' + cast(@startMonth as varchar(2)), 2) + '01') as [date] --start
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, [date])
    from [dates]
    where [date] < cast(@endYear as varchar(5)) + 
        RIGHT('0' + cast(@endMonth as varchar(2)), 2) + '01' --end
)
select cast(year([date]) as varchar(5)) + '-' + upper(left(datename(month, [date]), 3))
from [dates]
order by [date]
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26571)

Answer (score 1):

`@LowerBound` = 3 and `@UpperBound` = 2, so the inner WHILE loop never fires.

Add a condition such that if that is the case, add 12 to @UpperBound,

```
    SET @LowerBound = CAST(MONTH('1'+@StartMonth+'00') as INT)
    SET @UpperBound = CAST(MONTH('1'+@EndMonth+'00') as INT)
    if (@UpperBound < @LowerBound) set @UpperBound = @UpperBound + 12
```

FYI, `DateName( month , 13 )` evaluates to January.

Answer (score 1):

this should work

```
  DECLARE @StartYear AS INT,
            @EndYear  AS INT

DECLARE @LowerBound AS INT,
        @UpperBound  AS INT

DECLARE @StartMonth AS VARCHAR(10),
        @EndMonth  AS VARCHAR(10)

DECLARE @ConCatData VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ConCatData=''

SET @StartYear=2009
SET @EndYear=2010

SET @StartMonth='MAR '
SET @EndMonth='Jan'

WHILE(@StartYear <= @EndYear)
BEGIN

    SET @LowerBound = CAST(MONTH('1'+@StartMonth+'00') as INT)
    SET @UpperBound = CAST(MONTH('1'+@EndMonth+'00') as INT)
if (@UpperBound < @LowerBound) set @UpperBound = @UpperBound + 12;

    WHILE( @LowerBound <= @UpperBound )
    BEGIN
        SELECT @ConCatData=CAST(@StartYear AS VARCHAR)+'-'+ DateName( month , DateAdd( month ,@LowerBound , -1 ) )
        SET @LowerBound=@LowerBound+1
        PRINT @ConCatData
    END
    SET @StartYear=@StartYear+1
END

    enter code here
```